# is it normal for rake assets:precompile to launch the environment 3 times? (rails 3.2.3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

If I put in config/application.rb on a rails 3.2.3 app:

```
config.assets.precompile << "foo.js"
puts "hello"
```

I will see:

```
hello
hello
hello
```

Is this normal and expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a multi-process web server like passenger or unicorn, then yes.  The entire rails environment needs to be loaded into each process instance.